# How to insert an element into list at index in jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

i have set the list of split string in a variable as:

test = `a new version of app`

```
{% set new_index = test.split(' ') %}
```

I am trying to insert 'easy' after 'new' so tried as:

```
{% set new_index = test.split(' ').insert(2,' easy') %}
```

then `{{ new_index }}` which returned None

also tried with a new variable as:

```
{% set test1 = new_index.insert(2,' easy') %}
```

this also returned the same None

I read docs in which insert method is never used in examples too

Is there a way to achieve this, any help is appreciated TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test = "a new version of app"
new_index = test.split(' ').insert(2,'easy')
print(new_index)
```

**output**

```
None
```

**try This**

```
test = "a new version of app"
new_index = test.split(' ')
new_index.insert(2,'easy')
print(new_index)
```

**output**

```
['a', 'new', 'easy', 'version', 'of', 'app']
```

**Then Try this code for your jinja2 code**

```
{% set new_index = test.split(' ') %}
{% set another_new_index = new_index.insert(2,' easy') %}
```

then `{{ new_index }}` would return the required output

Comment: That gives me :jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '('  for second line in jinja

Comment: actually you should set it to another variable , `{% set new = new_index.insert(2,' easy') %}` and then `{{ new_index }}` gives the expected results.....Thanks for the idea mate , please update in answer